# Mock EF Core 5 Any() function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq, xunit

How can I Mock EF Any() function, please?

implementation:

```
_context.Reports.Any(x => ...);
```

test:

```
var reportDbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<Report>>();
var reportMock = DbContextMock.GetQueryableMockDbSet<Report>(reports);
var contextOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
var myContextMock = new Mock<MyDbContext>(contextOptionsBuilder.Options);

myContextMock.Setup(x => x.Reports.Any(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Report, bool>>>())).Returns(true);
```

Test throws a

> System.NotImplementedException : The method or operation is not
> implemented. error.

**UPDATE**

I make a silly mistake. I put the setup of Any() function after I call repository method.

Comment: You generally don't. EF provides in-memory implementations for such use cases; see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/testing/) for a more detailed overview and considerations for when you might want to involve an actual database. Even better is not attempting to mock your database layer directly, but going one level higher and mocking only your own business classes, so the fact that they deal with a database becomes an implementation detail.

Comment: You are right, but this is in an extended repository where a set some properties of objects depend on the function Any. Thx for the link I'll see it.

Comment: You are right it is not allowed mocking Any(). 'Extension methods (here: Queryable.Any) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.'